# Why is Thread join() useful when it defeats the sole purpose of thread viz concurrency

Tags: multithreading

Since thread join results in sequential execution of logic, what is the motivation to divide task between multiple thread in the first place? In other words, I am unable to conjure up a real scenario where thread join is actually needed.

Comment: Me neither. Join() is an invitation to continually create/terminate/destroy threads instead of using threadpools and app-lifetime threads, so wasting time/CPU on creation etc. overheads.  Join() is also good for deadlocking GUI apps on close, so preventing process termination.  Probably the worst inter-thread comms mechanism in existence.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `join()` if you want to launch multiple threads, and then wait until all of them have completed.

For example, launching 5 work items, each in their own thread, then calling `join()` on the 5 threads will allow you to process all 5 items concurrently, but block until they've all completed.

Note that many languages/frameworks have better alternatives than joining a thread explicitly, however.  For example, in the .NET world, the TPL allows you to schedule continuations that occur when one or more tasks (which can be mapped to threads if desired) all complete.

Comment: +1 Another important feature of `thread.join()` is memory synchronization.  The thread that calls `join()` which succeeds will, with more thread packages I know of, see the memory updates made by the thread it joined with.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you want a bunch of concurrent things to happen, and when they are all done, you want to combine all their results and move forward.

Take for example a web portal home page that needs to load data for a bunch of independent widgets on the server side. You might launch those data loads in parallel, and then have the main thread join on those (i.e. wait for them to finish) before rendering the overall page.

Answer (score 2):

In some situations you might hand out similar tasks to a bunch of threads, but you need all of them to complete to get the 'answer' you are looking for.

For example, if you were making a chess game, you could hand out potential sets of moves to individual threads and then wait until they all finished before selecting the 'best' one.

Answer (score -4):

It is not useful because it has more downsides than any other inter-thread comms mechanism known to man.  It actively encourages poor multithreading design with a high potential for boosting overheads and preventing process shutown, esp. in GUI apps.

If you can avoid using it, do so.

Comment: I down-voted because I've seen perfectly reasonable code that uses join() in Jetty, which is a reasonably complex application. It was used during shutdown, to wait for the threads in a thread pool to finish. There are better options in java.util.concurrent now, but that's no use if you want to support older versions of Java.

Comment: I've spent like 3 decades trying to stop devs using Join(), TThread.WaitFor etc. in the various languages.  My view remains the same.

Comment: Not trying to convince you (in fact, I agree there are almost always better options). Just explaining the down vote.